# How to clean git history?

Tags: git, github

Have a situation:

1. **[add many files]** Developer has added accidentally the external dependencies to the repository (thousands files).
2. **[make commit]** Next added over this commit several commits.
3. **[remove many files]** And then he saw the external dependencies in the repository, and remove them.
4. **[make commit]** And finnally make some commits and push it to master.

And now I see in Github stats, that developer added 1kk lines, and remove 1kk lines.

How can I clean git history? How change those commits and remove those files from history?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the github recommended [steps](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/#using-filter-branch) using either:

1. Use `filter-branch` and on step `3` instead of `Rackfile` add your directory or files that were added by accident. Also follow the step `8`, that is very important, since you are modifying the history.
2. Use [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), and also notify the other developers to do a rebase, since `BFG` will also alter the history.

Comment: @Basilevs Thanks, fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rebase -i <last good commit>` then in the editor choose to squash the commits the add and remove the files into one

This does have the disadvantage of meaning that you only have one commit where you might want the two change sets separate.

Also you will have rewritten history and need to be careful that your developers reset to your new history.

Comment: What if <first bad commit> also contain necessary changes? Is it possible to split commit?

Comment: Note that using just `rebase` will not remove the content from the git history.

Comment: @comm1x It's possible to have rebase stop at the bad commit and you can manual edit the tree to be in the state you want to commit

Comment: @dan if the two changes are squashed into one there is no commit left with the extra files, so they are removed from history.

Comment: @mcfedr That is true only if the changes are not yet pushed on github.

Comment: @dan that's why I say be careful with developers pulling - rebase rewrites history just like filter-branch, there is nothing stopping you pushing the changed history to github, but its bad practice for a bigger project

Comment: `git push -f origin master`

Comment: @comm1x Follow the steps prepared by github, linked in my answer.

Comment: @dan Ok, thanks, I need to learn and try both solution and after check them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [git-filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) with `--tree-filter` or `--index-filter`.

More info in the link.